# Extend `JpaRepository`, but only implement subinterfaces

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have some services fetching type-specific subclasses of an entity.

```
@Repository
interface MyFooWithIntRepo extends JpaRepository<MyFooWithInt, Long> {}
```

```
@Repository
interface MyFooWithFloatRepo extends JpaRepository<MyFooWithFloat, Long> {}
```

where

```
public interface MyFoo(){
    long getId();
    String getName();
    String getCode();
    ...
}
```

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractMyFoo implements MyFoo{
    @Column(name = "code")
    String code;
    ... getters, setters, interface implementation ...
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="int_myfoo")
public class MyFooWithInt implements MyFoo
    private int foo;
    ... getters, setters, interface implementation ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "float_myfoo")
public class MyFooWithFloat implements MyFoo
    private float foo;
    ... getters, setters, interface implementation ...
}
```

Database constraints guarantee unique `code` across all `MyFoo`s.
(The IDs, however, are unique only within the corresponding typed table.)

I now want to add a `findByCode` method to all repos, s.t. I can do

```
@Service
public class MyFooService{
    private MyFooWithIntRepo   intRepo;
    private MyFooWithFloatRepo floatRepo;
    [...]

    /*constructor-inject all the different repos*/

    Optional<? extends MyFoo> findByCode(String code){
        return combinedRepos()
            .map(repo -> repo.findByCode(code)
            .findFirst();
    }

    private Stream<JpaRepository<? extends MyFoo, Long>> combinedRepos(){
        return Stream.of(
            intRepo,
            floatRepo,
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

I could, of course, create a new interface,

```
public interface MyFooRepo<T extends MyFoo> {
    Optional<T> findByCode(String code);
}
```

and then have

```
@Repository
public interface MyFooWithIntRepo extends JpaRepository<MyFooWithInt, Long>, MyFooRepo<MyFooWithInt>
```

The problem with that is that when you cast to `MyFooRepo`, this way, you hide all the `JpaRepository` methods.

So either I'd have to add them all to the `MyFooRepo` interface, which is a hassle (especially because you'd need to rename them to avoid ambiguity),
or I'd have to insert casts all over the place -- which also is a hassle.

I'd much prefer if I could do something like

```
public interface MyFooRepo<T extends MyFoo> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    Optional<T> findByCode(String code);
}
```

And then

```
@Repository
public interface MyFooWithIntRepo extends MyFooRepo<MyFooWithInt> {}
```

Spring JPA doesn't seem to like that, though ...

```
[...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myFooRepo' defined in ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [ManagedType] was found for the key class [ch.cypherk.blah.MyFoo] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Managed] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>ch.cypherk.blah.MyFoo</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.
```

But I don't WANT that class to be turned into a functional `JpaRepository`, I just want it to be implemented in the `MyFooWithIntRepo` and the `MyFooWithFloatRepo` classes.

Any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is better than each entity has his own repository. Otherway, if you has a abstract class AbstractMyFoo you could implement a repository with the necessary methods (AbstractMyFooRepo)

Then, when you create classes childs of AbstractMyFoo, you can create a new repo chield of AbstractMyFooRepo.

Comment: The problem is that I still need to do a `getByCode` call on all repositories. so I need some kind of interface for when I create the `Stream.of(...)`

Comment: Define the getByCode method on the AbstractMyFooRepo. All child repos of AbstractMyFooRepo will inheret this method

Comment: But if I do that, how would I implement a `findById` method in the child classes? (remember, ID is unique only for a specific type) Do I need to override all the `JpaRepository` methods?

Comment: AbstractMyFooRepo is defined as a child of JpaRepository and define a custom method: getByCode. All repos childs of AbstractMyFooRepo will inhered the getByCode method and all methods fo JpaRepository